# What should I do when my supervisor is being disrespectful and too harsh

Tags: management, internship, employer-relations, employees, law

I am now currently doing my internships at this one company. This company is actually a branch, so here they have their person in charge for this branch. Unfortunately, on my first day of internships, I was shocked as my supervisor yelled at the staffs there. At that point of time, I was questioning myself 'Am i getting in trouble?'.

As days goes by, he started to show his true personality. He uses harsh words to the staffs, yelling at them and treating them like maid? He even ask one of the staff there to put food on a plate for him to eat. I was obviously shocked at his behaviour.

I find out that he's actually has been mistreating bis workers since before. At first I thought that its going to be better as long as it does not involves me. However, these past few weeks, everytime he's in a bad mood, I would getting involved too. He even hold me accountable for the one tasks that I've been assigned by the staff there. It's true that I've been assigned the work by the staff, however, due to its uncomplete details, I am unable to complete the task. I already ask the staff how to do it and she told me to wait. I've waited like she told me to do, and suddenly I'm getting mad by my supervisor.

I was also informed that he is quite racist with my ethnicity. The previous interns before me were the same ethnic with him, and he treats them kindly. When I reported this to the management of my university, they asked me to hold it out.
What should I do?

Comment: This is valuable experience.  Now you know what to look for in the future.

Comment: Would be valuable if you told us _where_ this happened.

Comment: **What should I do?** - The business world is full of bad bosses. This isn't the last one you're going to encounter in your career. Observe and take mental notes. Take no other action.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options.

Does the company have a Human Resource department? If so, speak to them about it. I would document all of your negative interactions with your manager (who was present, what was said, the topic of discussion, etc.) and present them to HR. Inform HR that he is creating a hostile work environment.

Confront your manager. I have been unprofessionally spoken to in front of colleagues in the past and chose to professionally ask my manager for a private meeting where I explained his unprofessional behavior and how I was not going to tolerate it. This has happened twice in my career and in both cases, it had positive results. The behavior stopped and I did not receive any negative ramifications. I generally suggest this as a first approach and then contact HR as mentioned above if it gets worse or does not stop.

Take it. If you're truly fearful of losing your job for whatever reason then you can keep your head down and deal with it. I don't recommend this approach because I think a person's self worth is more important than any job and it isn't in my nature to allow someone to belittle me however not everyone feels that way.